# Why explicit derivation of Show/Read in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, derived-types

We can't do `read someValue :: someDataType` or `show someValue` for every type because `deriving (Show, Read)` has to be written in the `data` declarations. Is there a case, other than mistake, where we don't want our type to be serializable?
Why is Show separated from Read? Is there a case, other than mistake, we only want to show some data and not read it? If not, why not have a single data type `Serializable`?

Just now, I'm using [the `Key` datatype of the Gloss library](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gloss/1.7.4.1/doc/html/Graphics-Gloss-Interface-Pure-Game.html#t%3aKey) which derives `Show` and not `Read`, which I don't understand. It's a shame because I wanted to put the configuration of the controls in a file and then read it, so the player can change the controls and have his own configuration.
I had to do wrappers for Key, SpecialKey and MouseButton, which is not a big deal but is useless.

```
data Key' = Char' Char | SpecialKey' SpecialKey | MouseButton' MouseButton
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)
convertKey x = case x of
    Char' c -> Char c
    SpecialKey' sk -> SpecialKey sk
    MouseButton' mb -> MouseButton mb
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Why is Show separate from Read**

I don't know why this was originally, but feel it should persist because some (very few) types can be shown, or have a placeholder string shown, but not read back in.  Functions are the typical example.

Another way to think about it:  It's very easy to place things in separate classes but very hard to deal with too many functions in one class that doesn't always make sense in the same contexts.  Many people feel the `Num` class is a prime example of this issue.

**How Can I `read` Key and other types not in `Read`**

Step one: send in a patch adding `Read` to the set of derived instances. Step two: make a work around by using standalone deriving:

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
deriving instance Show Key
```

Step three: Use CPP to make your code work with either version of the codebase, be it the Gloss library with a Read instances that Ben will someday release or the version without.

**Why isn't there a `Serializable` class?**

For starters, there is [a Serialize class](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/cereal/0.3.5.2/doc/html/Data-Serialize.html).  Also, text is a horrible way to serialize things.  Perhaps you'd want a lazier serialize class in which case you should see the [Binary class](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/binary/0.5.1.0/doc/html/Data-Binary.html).  If you're concerned about performance then you might like [blaze-builder](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-builder), though I've honestly never used it.

Comment: Thanks, I see. Excuse-me, I didn't understand quite well the steps for using `read` on non-`Read` types. What code should I put in?

Comment: @L01man I pasted the code above.  You put that `{-# LANGUAGE ... ` line at the top of your file and somewhere in your file be sure to include the `deriving instance Show Key` line.

Comment: It still says `main: Prelude.read: no parse`. I thought it would work without step 3... Sorry again; how do you achieve step 3?

Comment: Could you paste what you have somewhere like hpaste (or just edit your quesiton)?  Also, if you got this far then the program must have compiled and thus typechecked - so that much is good.  This error indicates your input string is not formatted how the program expects.

Comment: You're right, I had forgotten to remove an old `Key'` in the String. It works, now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 11):

First, not all data types can be shown, for instance functions cannot be shown, so not all data types can be shown (nor read).  The original Haskell definition specified that if no deriving clause was given then as many derived classes as is possible would be derived.  This made it difficult to know what classes were actually derived, so the Haskell definition was changed to force explicit deriving clauses.

Second, in the original Haskell definition the `show` and `read` functions where bundled together in the `Text` class.  This isn't much of a problem when you derive `Show` and `Read`, but it is a pain when you write them by hand.  You often want to define a special `show` function, but now you are forced to write a `read` function as well, so it's better to keep them separate.  Personally I almost always derive `Show`, but almost never `Read`.

The `Show` and `Read` classes are not really meant to be used for serialization, but rather for simple input and output.

Comment: I don't know enough Python, but I suspect the answer is no.

Comment: It's a personalizable way to `print` objects as strings.

Answer (score 7):

Not every type is serializable. How can you establish an isomorphism between `String -> String` and `String`? If you give me `Read` and `Show` instances for `String -> String`, I can find a function which isn't serialisable like this:

```
evil :: String -> String
evil s = map succ (read s s ++ " evil")
```

Suppose

```
read (show evil) = evil
```

We get

```
evil (show evil)
  = map succ (read (show evil) (show evil) ++ " evil")
  = map succ (evil (show evil) ++ " evil")
  = map succ (evil (show evil)) ++ "!fwjm"
```

so if `evil (show evil)` is defined, then it has a first character `c` satisfying `c = succ c`, which is impossible.

In general, functions can't be serialized. Sometimes, we write datatypes which pack up functions, so not every datatype is serializable either. E.g.,

```
data Psychiatrist
  = Listen (String -> Psychiatrist)
  | Charge Int
```

Sometimes, even for these types, you might choose to provide partial implementations of `Read` (with some cases missing) and `Show` (e.g., with placeholders for or tabulations of functions), but there is no canonical way to choose them or reason why you would expect both.

As others have mentioned, serious serialization is the preserve of `Serialize`. I tend to use `Show` and `Read` for diagnostic purposes, especially trying things out in ghci. For that purpose, `Show` is by far more useful, because ghci has a *Haskell* parser to do the reading.

Comment: I get the idea and I'll come back to understand your `evil` function! I'll also look at `Serialize`.